# RecyclerView with SelectionTracker

Tags: android, recyclerview, kotlin

Есть RecyclerView в котором содержится список маршрутов(эта часть работает, список отображается)
Создаю SelectionTracker:

```
mTracker = SelectionTracker
        .Builder<Route>(
            "test_routes",
            routes_rc_routeList,
            RouteKeyProvider(mRoutesAdapter),
            RouteDetailsLookup(routes_rc_routeList),
            StorageStrategy.createParcelableStorage(Route::class.java))
        .withSelectionPredicate(
                SelectionPredicates.createSelectSingleAnything<Route>())
        .withOnItemActivatedListener { item, e ->
                "item: ${item.selectionKey?.printableName}".toLog("OnItemActivatedListener")
                return@withOnItemActivatedListener true}
        .build()
```

где RouteKeyProvider:

```
class RouteKeyProvider(
    private val routeAdapter: RoutesListRecyclerViewAdapter
) : ItemKeyProvider<Route>(ItemKeyProvider.SCOPE_CACHED) {
    override fun getKey(position: Int): Route? = routeAdapter.getItem(
    override fun getPosition(key: Route): Int = routeAdapter.getPosition(key)
}
```

RouteDetailsLookup:

```
class RouteDetailsLookup(
    private val recyclerView: RecyclerView
) : ItemDetailsLookup<Route>() {
    override fun getItemDetails(e: MotionEvent): ItemDetails<Route>? = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(
        e.x,
        e.y
    )?.let {
        (recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(it) as? RouteViewHolder)?.getItemDetails()
    }
}
```

RouteItemDetails:

```
class RouteItemDetails(
    private val position: Int,
    private val route: Route?
) : ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Route>() {
    override fun getSelectionKey() = route
    override fun getPosition() = position
}
```

ВьюХолдер и адаптер самые простые, не вижу смысла выводить сюда.
В [туториале от гугла](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/selection/package-summary) сказано следующее

> When the user selects an item the library will record that in SelectionTracker then notify RecyclerView that the state of the item has changed. This will ultimately cause the value to be rebound by way of RecyclerView.Adapter#onBindViewHolder

В моем случае в логах я вижу срабатывает **OnItemActivatedListener**, но вьюшка не оповещается об изменениях, в следствии чего не вызывается **RecyclerView.Adapter#onBindViewHolder**. Также я на трекер накидываю наблюдателя **SelectionTracker.SelectionObserver** но ни один из его методов не отрабатывает.
Где я ошибся или чего не доделал?

**UPD:** при изменении списка срабатывают методы *onSelectionRefresh* и *onSelectionChanged* у **SelectionTracker.SelectionObserver**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, все было сделано правильно, просто выбор активируется долгим нажатием. После все нотифики стали прилетать и *onBindViewHolder* отрабатывать. К сожалению, это не то, что мне нужно было. Заставить селектор выделять без долгого нажатия у меня не вышло.